# Why is there no "Cover Horizontal" for iOS storyboard seques?

Tags: ios, ipad, storyboard, transition, segue

I'm putting together a quick slide show on the iPad thats always in landscape mode.  The easiest way that I can think to do this is a storyboard with swipe gestures to segue between slides.

The problem is, I want the transition to slide in the direction of my swipe, but I only have "Cover Vertical" to work with.  Is there any way to get a "Cover Horizontal" into Storyboard? Or perhaps some nifty code to hack it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://blog.jimjh.com/a-short-tutorial-on-custom-storyboard-segues.html  This is all I found... but didn’t get it working yet. Did you get it figured out?

Comment: Yeah I saw that tutorial and using that I got close.  Ultimately it was crashing after the segue, but I got it to at least slide the way I wanted.  It was too hokey so I changed the layout of the app and called it a day.

Comment: Dead link now. What was behind it?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's yet possible to do what you want, the options for the storyboards are quite limited at the moment.

I have done similar things in the past using a UIScrollView with paging enabled.